# Pass Python scripts for mapreduce to HBase

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

We have a HBase implementation over Hadoop. As of now all our Map-Reduce jobs are written as Java classes. I am wondering if there is a good way to use Python scripts to pass to HBase for Map-Reduce.

Comment: If you haven't looked at it already, look at `jython`. It allows for good integration between Java and Python.

Comment: @frb Do you know if anyone has successfully used a Jython class as a Map-Reducer and passed it into HBase?

Answer (score 5):

There is a good open-source library that you could use for this purpose. It's called `HappyBase` and available [here](https://github.com/wbolster/happybase). It uses the Thrift API for HBase to connect.

Here is an example of some simple HBase operations done with HappyBase:

```
import happybase

connection = happybase.Connection('localhost')
table = connection.table('my-table')

table.put('row-key', {'family:qual1': 'value1','family:qual2': 'value2'})
row = table.row('row-key')print row['family:qual1']  
# prints 'value1'
for key, data in table.rows(['row-key-1', 'row-key-2']):    
    print key, data  # prints row key and data for each row
for key, data in table.scan(row_prefix='row'):    
    print key, data  # prints 'value1' and 'value2'
row = table.delete('row-key')
```

So if you want to run a Map/Reduce job using Python to access HBase, what you can do is:

1. Install HappyBase on all your datanodes.
2. Use Python streaming as detailed [in the streaming section](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.15.2/streaming.html) to run your job on the cluster.

Comment: Thanks. AFAIK Hadoop streaming does not work for HBase. It works for a plain vanilla HDFS. Our data is being stored via HBase. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: HBase essentially uses HDFS as a storage. Can you share more details about what your jobs do? I assume you're doing some lookups and/or writes in HBase, in which case you could use an HBase client like the one I showed above to do this inside your MR job (note that HappyBase uses the Thrift gateway, not the REST one).

Comment: Our MR jobs do things like weighted avg. calculations. I understand that I can use HappyBase as a client for GETS/PUTS but I want to know if I will be able to write an MR job purely in Python and feed it to HBase - as HBase expects Java Classes. I don't understand what you mean by "...do this inside your MR job...". My MR job is in Java , how will I embed Python in it?

Comment: Can you add to your question a sample code from your Java M/R job and how you run it? Maybe I misunderstood your question, but right now it is not clear to me exactly what you would like to achieve.

Comment: I simply want to write a mapper and reducer in Python in lieu of Java.

Comment: And I'm using the org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job; class to create the MR job

Comment: If you want to write a mapper and reducer in Python, then I don't understand why you can't use Python streaming with an HBase client like happybase or something else? Here is a good example for writing mappers and reducers in Python: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

Comment: +1 for the happybase+streaming suggestion. I will give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: I am -1 on use of HappyBase + map/reduce. For one, this is going to pound your thrift gateway(s) as all the cluster nodes start retrieving HBase blocks. If you have a small number of thrift gateways, then you're likely to be making multiple data transfers  across hosts to even get to the processing of the data (from the regionserver to the gateway to the mapper to the reducer). Even if every cluster node runs a thrift gateway and the mapper connects to the local one, you still lose all data locality.

Answer (score -2):

You can very easily do map reduce programming with Python which would interact with thrift server. Hbase client in python would be a thrift client.

Comment: Jitendra: welcome to SO! Consider adding a reference to your answer showing how you'd use Python scripts with HBase instead of simply asserting that it's possible.